# Using integration to solve non-constant acceleration problems

Tags: calculus, classical-mechanics

The question is: A body moves along a straight line with acceleration $a$ in meters per second squared given by $a = \frac{7}{36}t$ where $t$ is the time in seconds. Initially the body is at rest at an origin $O$. The acceleration continues until $t = 6$, whereupon it ceases and the body is retarded to rest. During this retardation the acceleration is given by $a = -1/4t$. Find the value of $t$ when the body comes to rest and the displacement of the body from $O$ at that time.

I understand how to use integration to find velocity and displacement, I have written out the equation for velocity using integration but I am not sure what to do after this.

Comment: If you know the equation of velocity in terms of time, find $t$ such that velocity is $0$, i.e., body is at rest. For this evaluated value of $t$, find the displacement by integrating the velocity.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. My problem is that when I integrate it the velocity turns out to be negative (v= -1/8t^2) , so do I set this to be 0 and solve the equation? wouldn't that just give me t=0?

Comment: Not sure if you have evaluated the velocity correctly. Until $t = 6$, the velocity is given as $v = (7/72)t^2$. This means velocity at $t = 6$ is $v_0 = 3.5$. For $t > 6$, the velocity is given as $v = v_0 + \int_{6}^t (-0.25t) \ \mathrm{d} t$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks very much. I don't quite understand why you would add V0 to the velocity for t > 6 though?

Comment: Because that is the initial velocity. The equation is $\mathrm{d}v = a \ \mathrm{d}t$ . When you integrate it you have $\int_{v(t_0)}^{v(t)} \mathrm{d}v = \int_{t_0}^t a \ \mathrm{d}t$, which gives the left side as $v(t) - v(t_0)$, where $v(t_0)$ denotes the velocity at initial time $t_0$. When the acceleration is a constant, this yields you the well known equation $v = u + at$, where $u$ is the initial velocity.

Comment: Thanks so much. I have calculated t as 5.292s and the total displacement as 3.91m - is this correct?

Comment: You forgot to add the 6 in the time because the equation I gave is for $t > 6$. The displacement will have to be taken care of accordingly. Make sure you add the displacement from $t \leq 6$ and $t > 6$.

Comment: Thanks very much - hopefully won't make the same mistakes in tomorrow's mechanics test!

Answer (score 1):

start from $a = \frac{7}{36}t \ $ like below
$$a=\frac {dv(t)}{dt}= \frac{7}{36}t\\ \to dv(t)= \frac{7}{36}tdt\\\int_0^6dv(s)ds=\int_0^6\frac{7}{36}sds\\v(s)|_0^6=\frac{7}{36}\frac {s^2}{2}|_0^6\\v(6)-v(0)=3.5\\W.R.T. \ v(0)=0 \to v(6)=3.5
$$ for the second part $v(6)=3.5 \frac {m}{s}$ and now
$$a=\frac {dv(t)}{dt}=\frac{-1}{4}t \ \frac ms\\ dv(t)=\frac{-1}{4}tdt\\
\int_6^{t}dv(s)=\int_6^{t}\frac{-1}{4}sds\\v({t})-v(6)=\frac {-1}{8}(s^2)|_6^t\\v(t)-3.5=\frac {-1}{8}(t^2-36)$$ if you want to find when $v(t)=0$ solve the equation $$v(t)=3.5+\frac {-1}{8}(t^2-36)=0 \to t=8 \ sec$$
at the end , a figure can achieve them
[image]

Comment: Sorry, i didn't quite follow the penultimate step - where did the 36 come from? thank you

Comment: I will add some detail now